# Test Suites for testing comet server functionality through PHP

Tags: php, testing, comet, test-suite

What test suites are there for testing comet server functionality through PHP?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any PHP-solutions, but I do know you could use [yeti](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/08/25/introducing-yeti-the-yui-easy-testing-interface/) to do the testing using javascript.